# SQL to get grades

Tags: sql

I'm creating an application to store tests. The database schema is simplified below

```
id_student            id_teacher          grade second_test

student_1             teacher_1           10    'Y'
student_1             teacher_1           5     'N'
student_2             teacher_1           8     'N'
student_3             teacher_1           9     'N'
```

I need a query to get the grade of each student considering that if that student has a second test (which is a retrieval) the grade returned must be the one of the second test (and not the first).

So for that example, the result set should be

```
student_1             teacher_1           10    'Y'
student_2             teacher_1           8     'N'
student_3             teacher_1           9     'N'
```

I wrote a sql, but it's not working. Because it won't get the student_2 and student_3

```
SELECT
  m.id_student,
  m.grade
FROM
  mytable m
WHERE
  second_test = 'Y'
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM
      mytable
    WHERE
      id_student = m.id_student
      AND id_teacher <> m.id_teacher
      AND second_test = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: `where second_test = 'Y'` will only bring back student 1

Comment: Can you give us your table structure and fields please

Comment: It's given in the question. I help you to understand but what exactly do you need more?

Comment: Both conditions of your OR statement stipulate second_test = "Y", hence it will only return students with second_test = "Y" i.e. student_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one student can only have one or two records in your table, you could left join the first test to the second test.

```
select 
    t1.id_student,
    t1.id_teacher,
    coalesce(t2.grade,t1.grade)
from
    (select id_student, id_teacher, grade from my_table where second_test = 'N') as t1
left join
    (select id_student, id_teacher, grade from my_table where second_test = 'Y') as t2
on 
    t1.id_student = t2.id_student and t1.id_teacher = t2.id_teacher
```

If one student may have more than two test record, than you should using aggregation method in those two sub querys.

Comment: One student could have more than one test, depending on how many teacher applied tests, but for each teacher there will be two tests (first test and retrieval). What aggregation method can I use?

Comment: If so, don't need more aggregations, just add id_teacher in join conditions and sub querys. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.
First, take all students who have two grades and take the one from second test, then union it with those who have only 1 grade.

```
SELECT
    a.id_student, a.id_teacher, b.grade, b.second_test
FROM (
    SELECT
        id_student, id_teacher
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) a
    JOIN mytable b ON a.id_student = b.id_student AND a.id_teacher = b.id_teacher AND b.second_test = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT
    a.id_student, a.id_teacher, b.grade, b.second_test
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id_student, id_teacher
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) a
    JOIN mytable b ON a.id_student = b.id_student AND a.id_teacher = b.id_teacher
```

This answer can be easily modified to get latest grade even if you would have 5 grades for each student (depending on a flag).

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I use Jaugar Chang's answer :)